# Ran chkconfig but crond not starting on reboot on Amazon Linux

Tags: cron, boot, amazon-linux

I am trying to get the cron daemon to start on reboot on an instance of Amazon Linux (Linux version 3.14.57-34.46.amzn1.x86_64).
I have run:

```
$ sudo chkconfig crond on
```

If I run:

```
$ chkconfig --list crond
```

I get:

```
crond    0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:on
```

The system's default run level is 3.

Starting/stopping crond manually works fine, and the commands in my crontab are executed.

```
$ sudo service crond <start|stop|restart>
```

After reboot there are no warning or error logs in `/var/log/cron` (there are non-error logs once cron is started manually) or `/var/log/messages`. Am I missing something? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar problem, here's what the issue was: nginx was also set to start on boot and had a password-protected SSL certificate key. After the passphrase was removed from the key, crond started on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I met similar situation. but finally I solved it.

I tried 2 way.

(1) all requires update
  `sudo yum update`

(2) wait login to finish all initialization on AmazonLinux

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have tried updating and crond is still stopped on reboot